# How can I find the predecessor of a Natural with type-level parity checking?

Tags: haskell

I've been working with natural numbers with additional type-level parity information. `succ` has been successfully implemented in the most straightforward way:

```hs
succ :: Natural p -> Natural (Opp p)
succ = Succ
```

However, I'm still struggling with getting `pred` to typecheck. A minimal example:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilyDependencies #-}

data Parity = Even | Odd

type family Opp (p :: Parity) = (r :: Parity) | r -> p where
  Opp 'Odd = 'Even
  Opp 'Even = 'Odd

data Natural :: Parity -> * where
  Zero :: Natural 'Even
  Succ :: Natural p -> Natural (Opp p)

pred :: Natural (Opp p) -> Natural p
pred (Succ n) = n
```

What can I do to successfully implement `pred`? Right now I'm getting many different large and complicated type errors, especially `could not deduce Opp p ~ p1`.

Comment: Weird. I added the obvious injectivity axiom (`type family Opp (n :: Parity) = (n' :: Parity) | n' -> n`), and the error I get is "Could not deduce `p1 ~ p` from the context `Opp p ~ Opp p1`". Isn't that exactly the deduction that the injectivity axiom is supposed to let you make??

Comment: @DanielWagner Injectivity annotations are not exploited by GHC for anything except for allowing some types that would be otherwise considered ambiguous. Only for that. They are not used, as one would expect, to infer a ~ b from F a ~ F b. Personally, I consider them to be nearly useless, in their current form.

Comment: I don't know how to write `pred` with that type. I think an additional singleton argument for `p` is needed.

Comment: I'm happy to write it with a different type as long as the parity checking is preserved (and of course it does what `pred` is supposed to do). How would such an argument work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @chi indicated,

> Injectivity annotations are not exploited by GHC for anything except for allowing some types that would be otherwise considered ambiguous. Only for that. They are not used, as one would expect, to infer `a ~ b` from `F a ~ F b`. Personally, I consider them to be nearly useless, in their current form.

So you have to define `Natural` a bit differently:

```
data Natural :: Parity -> * where
  Zero :: Natural 'Even
  Succ :: (p ~ Opp s, s ~ Opp p) => Natural p -> Natural s
```

Now you can get both of the things you need.

Comment: This along with @danidiaz 's suggestion to change the order to `pred :: Natural p -> Natural (Opp p)` did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Given singletons for `Parity`:

```
data SParity :: Parity -> Type where
  SEven :: SParity Even
  SOdd :: SParity Odd
```

We can prove the injectivity of `Opp`

```
oppInj' :: Opp p ~ Opp q => SParity p -> SParity q -> p :~: q
oppInj' SEven SEven = Refl
oppInj' SOdd SOdd = Refl
```

Now we can define:

```
data Natural' :: Parity -> Type where
  Zero' :: Natural' Even
  Succ' :: SParity p -> Natural' p -> Natural' (Opp p)
pred' :: SParity p -> Natural' (Opp p) -> Natural' p
pred' p (Succ' q n) = case oppInj' p q of Refl -> n
```

You may safely perform erasure to get rid of all the singleton junk:

```
-- for maximum symmetry, instead of relying on type applications we could
-- just substitute Proxy# in place of SParity everywhere, but meh
oppInj :: forall p q. Opp p ~ Opp q => p :~: q
oppInj = unsafeCoerce Refl -- we know this is OK because oppInj' exists
data Natural :: Parity -> Type where
  Zero :: Natural Even
  Succ :: Natural p -> Natural (Opp p)
pred :: forall p. Natural (Opp p) -> Natural p
pred (Succ (n :: Natural q)) = case oppInj @p @q of Refl -> n
```

This pattern, doing something with singletons and then erasing them for an improvement in space and time (here it's just a constant factor) is common when doing dependently typed programming in Haskell. Normally, you wouldn't write `Natural'` or `pred'`, but they are useful as guides for writing the erased versions.

PS: Make sure to handle the `Zero` case!

Comment: Richard Eisenberg has suggested a "safer" version, where you prove `oppInj` legitimately and then use `RULES` to rewrite to `unsafeCoerce`. But since even the legit `oppInj` is O(1), you don't really even *need* to erase!

Comment: Oh, I guess you want erasure to avoid cluttering the `Succ` constructor... That's reasonable.

Comment: I've said this before, but I avoid using `RULES` for that purpose because they just don't erase far enough, as you've noticed.

Answer (score 4):

How about this slightly different formulation. Notice the change in the position of `Opp`:

```
data Parity = Even | Odd

type family Opp (n :: Parity) = (m :: Parity) | m -> n where
    Opp 'Even = 'Odd
    Opp 'Odd  = 'Even

data Natural :: Parity -> * where
  Zero :: Natural 'Even
  Succ :: Natural (Opp p) -> Natural p

pred :: Natural p -> Natural (Opp p)
pred (Succ n) = n
```

This makes `pred` "go with the grain". The compiler doesn't need to "undo" the `Opp` application, is just "works forward".

But wait, doesn't this shift the problem to the `Succ` constructor? Actually, yes, if I remove the injectivity annotation, the type of terms like

```
ghci> Succ (Succ Zero)
```

fails to be inferred. But why the injectivity annotation wasn't sufficient before, but it is now? I don't know.